# java classes Object oriented programming

Tags: java

can someone explain to me what is happening in this class, because i can't understand the initialization of the array of strings of courses and the grades

```
public class stud{
  int id;
  String nam;
  String courses[];
  double grades[];
  int maxSize, size;

  public stud(int d, String n, int ms)
  {
    id = d;
    nam = n;
    courses = new String[ms];
    grades = new double[ms];
    size=0;
  }
  public void addCourse(String nc, double g)
  {
    courses[size]=nc;
    grades[size]=g;
    size++;
  }
  public void print()
  {
    System.out.println(id+ " "+nam);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      System.out.println(courses[i]+ " "+grades[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The line `courses = new String[ms];` allocates memory for the array `courses` which can store `ms` no. of values.

Comment: Uhh, not understanding in the sense of syntax or semantically ?

Comment: Sounds like you really need to read the documentation or look at some  tutorials. Literally just Google "java array tutorial". -1 for obvious lack of research effort.

Comment: i strongly suggest checking http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Added a few comments below.

```
public class stud {
    int id;
    String nam;
    String courses[];
    double grades[];
    int maxSize, size;

    public stud(int d, String n, int ms)
    {
        // initialise the attributes
        id = d;
        nam = n;

        // create empty arrays with a size of ms
        courses = new String[ms];
        grades = new double[ms];

        //point to the first item in the array
        //Also gives the number of values in the array
        size=0;
     }

     public void addCourse(String nc, double g)
     {
         //Add a course name and grade into the array
         //they are added at the location pointed to by 'size'
         courses[size]=nc;
         grades[size]=g;

         //Increment the pointer to the next empty array location
         size++;
     }

     public void print()
     {
         System.out.println(id+ " "+nam);

        //Iterate over the arrays until we get to the size
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            System.out.println(courses[i]+ " "+grades[i]);
     }
}
```

Note that as it stands it will not output anything. The addCourse method would need to be called to add courses.

This is also rather badly coded, you might want to look at a

```
Map<String, Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

String courses[];

double grades[];

Those are two Attributes in java class. courses array can store String(String is not a primitive data type)  type object arrays. And double grades array can store double type array references.